# How to retrieve password for IBM Watson Discovery service?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I want to get my username and password for the IBM Watson Discovery services on my IBM Cloud account, but I keep on getting this "apikey". Could you tell me how to get the username and the password instead of the APIkey?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

More and more of the IBM Cloud services, including the Watson services, are migrated from a username / password combination for authentication to IAM (identity and access management) tokens. Thus, if you recently created that service it is very likely that you have to use the API token.

See the [Discovery API docs for authentication methods](https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/discovery#authentication). You pass in just the token and not the username / password combination.